# Does an actual dimmer switch exist?

Tags: lighting

I'm looking for a dimmer switch. Not a knob I can turn, an actual on/off switch.

I want to have dim lights for the bathroom, but rather than a knob just a switch that turns them on dim or off. And then another switch that turns them on full.

Does such a thing exist? I'm in the UK so needs to be compatible with UK wiring.

Comment: there are lightbulbs that change brightness levels by way of briefly flicking the light switch off-on

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to avoid being blinded at night so ideally no flicking needed.

Comment: Is there an option for an additional light source within the existing fixture? I'm thinking something led that's on an entirely separate switch from the original switch.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate Yeah I was thinking that, just have a separate night light circuit.

Comment: you could wire the lights as a 3-way, then put the dimmer in a hidden spot. Or maybe put a dimmer in series with the light, which would work, but might be of uncertain code compliance.

Comment: Ok, just re-read your challenge. You need to put a regular switch in parallel to a dimmer. When the switch is off, the dimmer dims, when on, the dimmer is shorted out of the circuit. Another switch in series can turn the whole thing on or off.

Comment: @dandavis can you do a diagram?

Comment: I'm mobile, but I can describe the connections; all hot. There's a dimmer and two regular light switches, let's call them "onoff" and "hilo". Breaker>onoff's in. Onoff's out to hilo's in AND dimmer's in. Hilo's out to dimmer's out AND to light fixture. You can bury the dimmer once low's been adjusted. The hilo switch simply bypasses the dimmer when on, giving full brightness.

Answer (score 5):

You're making it harder than it is. You're going to laugh when you realize.

### It's common to have fixtures that take multiple bulbs

In the fixture wiring, they typically give separate access to each light's "live" wire.

So simplicity itself. Run power to the switch, then run 3-core wire from switch to light.  Now you can use the standard UK connection block to wire it so each bulb is controlled by a different switch.

Now, put a tiny bulb in one socket and a big bulb in the other.

Comment: That's probably the easiest solution. Do you know of any models suitable for use in a bathroom? I can't find any.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about the UK but in the USA, there are on-off switches with a slider for the on dim level, such as this Luton:
[image]or this one:[image]

I expect that something similar is available in the UK.

Comment: Thanks, I have not seen these for sale in the UK. However they aren't really want I want because I am trying to avoid needing to use any analogue control. Just an on/off switch that goes directly into a fixed dim state, and another that goes directly into a full on state.

Comment: I have a duplex wall outlet in my bathroom to plug in a hair dryer.  I keep a small C7 or led night light in the open outlet. It gives enough light for a nighttime stop without needing the bright room light. There are even night lights with light sensors so they don't come on until it's dark.

Comment: @EricSimpson that was plan B, just get a motion sensor night light. Maybe battery powered.